# backendError 500 (Bug in nextPageToken)

Tags: google-drive-api

For some of the users iterating through the list of files started producing error **500 (backendError)**. Very few cases, but still.

Close investigation showed that sometimes after requesting a list of files strange **nextPageToken** was returned. Here is an example:

```
!!|~EAIaggELEgA6egpg96K5Moz_____f_8AAP__AAD_7qNsfh7Iy8rJyMnDy8bLytHI0bDOy6W4rZ6wvqmc_wAA__8A_v_-f_8A_wDuo2x-HsjLysnIyc7LxsvK0cjRsM7LpbitnrC-qZz_AP_-EJzHASFVhA7Kvoa7STkAAAAAc81GXUgBDEAAIgsJ4YZTXBEABAAgBg
```

This part right here "**!!|~**" (start of the string) was causing the errors. Removing it fixed the issue.

There were not so many cases. But still, can this be a bug?

UPDATE 1.

Here is a code sample using [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/). But the error reproduced only for few users. So there are not a lot of chances of reproducing it.

```
    $client = new Google_Client( );
    // ... setup client

    $driveService = new Google_DriveService( $client );
    $parameters = array();

    try{
        do{
            $files = $driveService->files->listFiles( $parameters );
            $parameters['pageToken'] = $files->nextPageToken;

            // ... 

            } while( $parameters['pageToken'] );
        }
    catch( Google_ServiceException $exception ) {
        // ... handle exception
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you post the exact code and procedure to reproduce this?

Comment: @JunYoungGwak Thank You for the reply. I have updated the question with code sample.